# SKTexture: Error loading image resource

Tags: xcode, swift, spritekit

Непонятно в чем проблема, не подскажите ли как это исправить.

Вот код:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var Ma = SKSpriteNode()

    var TextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas()
    var TextureArray = [SKTexture]()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {


        TextureAtlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "bee.atlas")

        for i in 0...TextureAtlas.textureNames.count{

             var Name = "c\(i).png"
             TextureArray.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: Name))
         }

         Ma = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: TextureAtlas.textureNames[0] )

         Ma.size = CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)
         Ma.position = CGPoint(x: 250, y: 250)
         self.addChild(MainGuy)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
         Ma.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(TextureArray, timePerFrame: 1.0)))
    }

}
```

Вылетает ошибка:

```
SKTexture: Error loading image resource:
```

Comment: в какой строке ошибка?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko ошибки в коде нет, код компилируется, имитатор айфона открывается, после нажатия должна стартовать анимация, но вместо этого появляется красный крестик, а в терминале появляется эта ошибка. Вот я и не понимаю в чем проблема. Все файлы .png, в папке .atlas, пытался атлас загружать и в .xcassets, и в файл самого приложения, всё равно ничего не меняется.

Comment: поставьте брейкроинт и выполняйте построчно, пока не выскочит ошибка. и напишите после какой строки она выскакивает

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Добавил breakpoints, приложение не компилирется. Строчка `    var Ma = SKSpriteNode()    `  подсвечивается зеленым и пишет "Thread 1: breakpoint 29.5 30.3 31.332.5 33.3"

Comment: :facepalm: это и есть брейкпоинт. найдите кнопку "step over" и жмите ее, и после каждого нажатия смотрите не появилась ли ошбика

Comment: попробуйте `var Name = "c\(i)"` - обычно расширение не надо указывать

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko после огромного количества нажатий на клавишу step over, вылезает вот такая ошибка `Test game[3641:237618] CUICatalog: Invalid Request: requesting subtype without specifying idiom`    в строчке `0x1062314a3 <+703>:  movq   0xc0371e(%rip), %rsi      ; "_wantsReapplicationOfAutoLayoutWithLayoutDirtyOnEntry:"
`